# react-tranisition-group use flex-box for react-router transition

Tags: css, reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm following the tutorial to add transition for `react-router` page use `react-transition-group`. 
My page content all wrapped into the container, and I use flex-box to center the container.

However, it leads to transition cannot apply properly.

I expect page transition should be in the container, either from left to right or right to left.
I'm trying to use `position:relative` in container and `position:absolute` for transition class, seems doesn't work at all

[code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-in-container-0z17n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Any ideas are welcome!

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-tiger-transition](https://pedrobern.github.io/react-tiger-transition/) for full page transitions with react-router.

Here is the demo:

[image: demo-gif]

(I'm the author)